# Class variables remains the same after re-initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class

I'm doing a two player tic-tac-toe game. Everytime the user presses on New Game button the class MultiPlayerGame goes through initialisation again. The problem is that the variables inside of it (`gameMatrix`, `firstPlayer`, `cellsLeft`) remains the same as before. I set a breakpoint inside the declarations of these variables and they seem to be restarted but everytime I print the values of those variables they were like before initialisation thus my game is not working.

```
//
//  MultiPlayerGame.swift
//  Tic Tac Toe
//
//  Created by Andrei Vataselu on 11/7/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Andrei Vataselu. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit



class MultiPlayerGame{

    enum playerTurn {
        case firstPlayer // valoarea 0 in gameMatrix
        case secondPlayer // valoarea 1 in gameMatrix
    }


    var turnToPlay : playerTurn
    var gameMatrix : [Int]
    var cellsLeft : Int

    static var game = MultiPlayerGame()

    private init(){
        self.turnToPlay = .firstPlayer

        // Prepara tabla pentru joc

        self.cellsLeft = 9

        self.gameMatrix = [2,2,2,
                           2,2,2,
                           2,2,2]


        for i in 0..<mpImages.count {
            mpImages[i].isHidden = true
            mpButtons[i].isHidden = false
        }

        mpNewGameButton.isHidden = true

        mpTurnLabel.text = "X turn"
        mpTurnLabel.isHidden = false

        mpWinningImg.isHidden = true
        mpWinningLabel.isHidden = true

    }

    static func getMultiplayerGame() -> MultiPlayerGame {
        return game
    }

    static func newGame(){
        game = MultiPlayerGame()
    }

    func actionCell(senderTag: Int,gameMatrixValue: Int, imageToChange: UIImage){
        gameMatrix[senderTag] = gameMatrixValue
        mpButtons[senderTag].isHidden = true
        mpImages[senderTag].image = imageToChange
        mpImages[senderTag].isHidden = false
        cellsLeft -= 1
     }

    func showEnding(imageToShow: UIImage){
        mpWinningImg.image = imageToShow
        mpWinningImg.isHidden = false
        mpTurnLabel.isHidden = true
        mpNewGameButton.isHidden = false

        if turnToPlay == .firstPlayer {
            mpWinningLabel.text = "X WINS"
        } else {
            mpWinningLabel.text = "O WINS"
        }
        mpWinningLabel.isHidden = false

        //disableButtons
        for i in 0..<mpImages.count {
            mpButtons[i].isHidden = true
        }

    }

    func endGame(winState: Int) {
        switch winState {
        case 1:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState1"))
        case 2:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState2"))

        case 3:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState3"))

        case 4:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState4"))

        case 5:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState5"))

        case 6:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState6"))

        case 7:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState7"))

        case 8:
            showEnding(imageToShow: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "winState8"))

        case 9:
            mpWinningLabel.text = "TIE"
            mpWinningLabel.isHidden = false
            mpNewGameButton.isHidden = false


        default: break
        }
    }

    func checkEndGame() {
        if gameMatrix[0] == gameMatrix[4] && gameMatrix[4] == gameMatrix[8] && gameMatrix[0] != 2 {
            endGame(winState: 7)
        } else if gameMatrix[2] == gameMatrix[4] && gameMatrix[4] == gameMatrix[6] && gameMatrix[2] != 2{
            endGame(winState: 8)
        } else if gameMatrix[0] == gameMatrix[3] && gameMatrix[3] == gameMatrix[6] && gameMatrix[0] != 2 {
            endGame(winState: 1)
        } else if gameMatrix[1] == gameMatrix[4] && gameMatrix[4] == gameMatrix[7] && gameMatrix[1] != 2{
            endGame(winState: 2)
        } else if gameMatrix[2] == gameMatrix[5] && gameMatrix[5] == gameMatrix[8] && gameMatrix[2] != 2{
            endGame(winState: 3)
        } else if gameMatrix[0] == gameMatrix[1] && gameMatrix[1] == gameMatrix[2] && gameMatrix[0] != 2 {
            endGame(winState: 4)
        } else if gameMatrix[3] == gameMatrix[4] && gameMatrix[4] == gameMatrix[5] && gameMatrix[3] != 2 {
            endGame(winState: 5)
        } else if gameMatrix[6] == gameMatrix[7] && gameMatrix[7] == gameMatrix[8] && gameMatrix[6] != 2{
            endGame(winState: 6)
        }
        else if cellsLeft == 0{
            endGame(winState: 9)
        }
    }

    func clickedCell(senderTag : Int) {
        if gameMatrix[senderTag] == 2 && cellsLeft != 0{
            if turnToPlay == .firstPlayer{
                actionCell(senderTag: senderTag, gameMatrixValue: 0, imageToChange: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "x"))
                checkEndGame()
                turnToPlay = .secondPlayer
                mpTurnLabel.text = "O turn"
            } else {
                actionCell(senderTag: senderTag, gameMatrixValue: 1, imageToChange: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "zero"))
                checkEndGame()
                turnToPlay = .firstPlayer
                mpTurnLabel.text = "X turn"
            }

    }
}
}
```

This is how I use it in my ViewController

```
var game = MultiPlayerGame.getMultiplayerGame()

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        game.clickedCell(senderTag: sender.tag)
    }

    @IBAction func newGameButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        MultiPlayerGame.newGame()
    }
```

Comment: could you show how you instantiate your game and how you call newGame?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Edited the answer to add a way that allows you to retrieve the updated static game every time without having to manually change your variable always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `game` **has a copy** of your class static variable and when you call `newGame` the static variable changes but your `var game` doesn't.

After you call `newGame` you **need to reassign** your game variable with `game = MultiPlayerGame.getMultiplayerGame()`

I did a short example to illustrate what I mean, you can reproduce it on a playground:

```
class Game {
    var a: Int

    static var game = Game()

    private init() {
        a = 0
    }

    static func newGame() {
        game = Game()
    }
}

var g = Game.game
g.a = 2

Game.newGame()
print(g.a)                  // value is 2, but you are probably expecting 0

var newGame = Game.game
print(newGame.a)            // value is 0, as it should
g = Game.game
print(g.a)                  // value is 0, as it should
```

Even that you have `var game = MultiPlayerGame.getMultiplayerGame()` inside your controller, that will only be called when you instantiate the controller the first one.

You can change the getter to be custom and to get the new instance of the *game* always, like this:

```
var game: MultiPlayerGame {
   get {
       return MultiPlayerGame.getMultiplayerGame()
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Also the 'game' field of MultiPlayerGame is accessible without the getter and/or computed property.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thank you for your answer!